# AngularFullstack deployment xdg-mime: command not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, server

I deployed my app generated by AngularFullstack https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack on my server after I installed nodeJS.

Now when I execute `grunt serve:dist` I recive the following error:

```
myApp/node_modules/open/vendor/xdg-open: line 584: xdg-mime: command not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:9000'
 Use --force to continue.
```